# java contravariance doubt

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

I read this post about contravariance:

> Let's now introduce another wildcard: `? super`. Given a supertype `B` of
>   a type `A`, then `C<B>` is a subtype of `C<? super A>`:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
List<? super Apple> = fruits;
```

but why `C<B>` is a subtype and not a supertype?

Comment: `C<? super B>` is a super type of `C<? super A>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<? super Apple` means **a list of some unknown supertype of `Apple`**. In such a variable you can put a `List<Apple>`, `List<Fruit>` (assuming `Fruit` is a supertype of `Apple`) or `List<Object>`, for example.

This is exactly the meaning of supertype: `List<? super Apple>` is more general than `List<Apple>`.

- Into a `List<Apple>` you can put apples, and nothing else. Everything you get out of the list is an apple.
- Into a `List<? super Apple>` you can put apples (nothing else, since you don't know the exact type). Everything you get out of the list is an object, but we don't know what kind of object (since it could be a `List<Object>`, for example).

If we use `List<? extends Apple>`, it is similar: It means **a list of some unknown subtype of `Apple`**. This might be a `List<Apple>`, `List<GoldenDelicious>`, `List<GrannySmith>`, `List<Jonagold>` and so on.

- Into a `List<Apple>` you can put apples (all types of apples), and everything you get out of it is an apple.
- Into a `List<? extends Apple>` you can't put anything - as you don't know which subtype of Apple was actually used. But everything we get out of this is in fact an apple.

We can do **all things and some more** with a `List<Apple>` than with `List<? super Apple>` or with `List<? extends Apple>` - e.g. it is a **subtype** of both of these wildcard types.

(The same applies to all generic types and their wildcard variants, it is just more easy to see for lists and similar container types.)

Comment: Ok but I don't understand why C<B> is a subtype and not a supertype!

Comment: If you can do more things with objects from a type, then it is more specific, it is a subtype.

Comment: Sorry but writing List<? super Apple> = fruits is very non-intuitive because Fruit is a supertype of an Apple and not a subtype so really I don't understand how we can say that in the lower-bound List<Fruit> is a subtype of List<Apple>...... arghhhh

Comment: No, `List<Fruit>` is in **no sub/supertype relation at all** to `List<Apple>`. Only the wildcard types are supertypes of the non-wildcard ones.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how contravariance works. **Consumer of fruits is a subtype of consumer of apples**, because it can consume apples as well, thus it supports operations defined for consumer of apples (unlike producers that are covariant, i.e. producer of apples is a subtype of producer of fruits).

I.e. you should use contravariance when your `List` acts as a consumer, for example:

```
public void fillWithApples(List<? super Apple> basket) {
    basket.add(new Apple());
}

List<Apple> basketOfApples = ...;
fillWithApples(basketOfApples);

List<Fruit> basketOfFruits = ...;
fillWithApples(basketOfFruits);

List<Object> basketOfAnything = ...;
fillWithApples(basketOfAnything);
```

Answer (score 2):

A useful rule for thinking about type hierarchies is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, it says that A being a subtype of B means that you can use A anywhere that you can use B. It is generally the case that the converse doesn't hold.

For example, let's say i am an evil king who demands a tribute from his subjects in the form of a piece of `Fruit`. Can you bring me an instance of `Apple`? Yes, of course. So an apple is a subtype of fruit. Over the mountains, there is [another evil king](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) who demands tribute from his subjects in the form of `Apple`s. Can you bring him a `Banana`, or some other piece of `Fruit`? No! He'll have you trampled to death by ponies if you do.

So, for you to live a long and happy life in my kingdom, you will need a supply of `Fruit`. You could keep this supply in a `List`. Could you keep it in a `List<Fruit>`? Yes, no problem. How about a `List<Apple>`? Fine, because i'll accept `Apple`s. So for the purposes of *production*, `List<Apple>` is a subtype of `List<Fruit>`. Over the mountains in the land of the other evil king, of course, you can only have a `List<Apple>`, unless you want to spend a lot of time casting the contents of a `List<Fruit>` to `Apple`s, which unless you're a wizard is pretty tiresome.

Now, after tribute day every year, i have a mountain of fruit. I don't even like fruit, so i have to put it somewhere. The obvious place is a `List<Fruit>`. Could i instead use a `List<Apple>` here? No! Because some of my dear subjects might bring me `Banana`s, and i would not be able to put those in such a list. However, over the mountains, a different situation obtains. The evil king there is only interested in `Apple`s, so he can happily use a `List<Apple>` to store his nutritious hoard. But can he use a `List<Fruit>`? Yes! Because an `Apple` is a `Fruit`, so he can quite easily put them in such a list. It's going to be fiddly when he wants to get them out again, but he can put them in quite happily. So, for the purpose of *consumption*, we see that someone who can use a `List<Apple>` can also use a `List<Fruit>`, and so we have the perverse situation that `List<Fruit>` is a subtype of `List<Apple>`. This is why i don't go over to the other evil kingdom much. Funny place.

Still, it's better than the Haskell Republic.

Comment: Nice story ... you might want to include the `List<? super Apple>` and `List<? extends Fruit>`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the rule "An instance of a subtype `class sub` should be assignable where ever an instance of `class supertype` is expected , it is pretty much evident.

Extend it further - Imagine an operation done to `List<? super A>` , - This operation will make sense on a `List<B>` , but not vice-versa.